# Filter serializer field's queryset based on current instance

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

In a HyperlinkedModelSerializer like the one below, how can I filter the set of related instances for the `other_model_objects` field based on the "current" instance of the model? (Maybe by using the queryset parameter in some way?)

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    other_model_objects = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=OtherModel.objects.filter(foo=current_instance.field),
        view_name='othermodel-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('other_model_objects',)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried subclassing `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and override `get_queryset` as stated in the docs: [CustomRelationalFields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) ?

Something like:

```
class MyFilteredHyperlinkedRelatedField(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # ... filter queryset
        return queryset

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    other_model_objects = MyHyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=OtherModel.objects.all(),
        view_name='othermodel-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('other_model_objects',)
```

I think you can access `MyModelSerializer` instance in `get_queryset` using `self.parent`, however I am not sure that is documented/stable.

**EDIT**

`queryset` parameter (and `get_queryset` method) are only used for validation during creations or updates. It is not about retrieving the values of the field, it is just about the allowed values for that field.

If you want to filter the values based on the instance I could suggest to update your model with a method returning the filtered values you would like:

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    def filtered_other_model(self):
        return self.other_model_relation_name.filter(....)
```

and then use the [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) parameter:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    other_model_objects = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=OtherModel.objects.all(),
        view_name='othermodel-detail',
        source = 'filtered_other_model'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('other_model_objects',)
```

Comment: Using `self.parent` I get an instance of `rest_framework.relations.ManyRelatedField` but `self.parent.instance` throws an `AttributeError`

Comment: With `self.root` I get the serializer which has an `instance` attribute. However, it only works on the detail view, not in the list view where `instance` is `None`

Comment: Indeed I forgot about the `many=True`, what does self.parent.parent give you? If I recall correctly, in many relations you have a ListSerializer in the middle.

Comment: Hmm.. `get_queryset` doesn't actually get called at all on the list view. (What I saw earlier was the `create` calls that DRF sends on the api view, switching to the JSON view I can see that no calls are made)

Comment: Indeed, it is only for validation: [The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)
You should reword your question to tell what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why should I reword the question? I'm still searching for the same thing

Comment: because I have answered your question :) which is how to make `queryset` parameter of a  `HyperlinkedRelatedField` dynamic. I think you are looking for filtering values of many related field during serialization aren't you ? I think the example you gave is misleading me. I have updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137689/discussion-between-michael-and-oskar-persson).